# GETTING A TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.7

I've a text file that consists of names. I want the user to type any 3 names and add them to an empty list, For each name we'll tell the user whether they are nearby. But I am getting an error which starts from `setting_near`.

```
user = input('Name any1 who is near to you ').split(',')
friends_open = open('friends.txt', 'r')
friends_read = friends_open.readlines()
friends_open.close()

near_by  = []
near_by.append(user)

setting_near = set(near_by)
setting_friends = set(friends_read)

intersect = setting_near.intersection(setting_friends)

for n in intersect:
    print(f'your {intersect} friend is here!! meet him ')
```

Comment: I want user's name  that matches to  my 'friends.txt' should be printed

Comment: Yah, I wanted to concatenate user and near_by

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using `append`, which will add the list `user` to the list `near_by`. `append` doesn't concatenate, it adds to the list.

Change that to [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), which does concatenate:

```
near_by.append(user)
```

Comment: To add to this, the `unhashable type: 'list'` error. The hash of an object is used to determine if the object has already been added to a set. Only immutable objects (eg objects that cannot be modified) can be hashed, eg a `str`, `datetime`, `tuple` etc. Mutable objects like a `list` cannot be hashed as changing the contents of a list would change the value of the hash and could allow duplicate (or equivalent) items in a set.

Comment: @Tim Ya. I thought about closing this as the typical dupe that explains that, but the problem is more that they're using the wrong method, not that they're trying to intentionally hash a list. When I get a sec, I'll add something.

Comment: realise that, but I always like to include the reason for the error they are getting in answers to help improve understanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim and Carcigenicate for the brief explanation.